# Check if button has been pressed

Tags: javascript, if-statement, button

I want to add an if statement that checks if the user is undefined for my program. It should alert: "no more profiles".
The problem is that my "likeId" is undefined to start with and I will get the alert first time i run the function. I would like to know that I can make an if statement that checks if a certain button has been pressed exactly one time.

This is my code:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('likeId') == "undefined"){
    alert("no more profiles to swipe")
}
```

My code should look something like this:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('likeId') == "undefined" && Button has been clicked exactly one time){
        alert("no more profiles to swipe")
    }
```

Comment: What does the button do? Can you describe the problem more clearly?

Comment: Bind an event handler to the button that increases a counter on click. Then compare the value of the counter in your `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a counter when the function tied to the button is called. You then check if `buttonClickedCounter == 1` and you should be good to go.